# Introductory material for effective potential in thermal QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, symmetry-breaking, effective-field-theory, thermal-field-theory

I'm looking for materials that systematically deal with both thermal and quantum corrections to the effective potential to all loop orders at a beginner-friendly level with prerequisites of QFT before standard model.